# How do I connect to a LAN machine service such as redis？

Tags: docker, laradock

- I created two containers php-fpm and nginx
- My native IP is 192.168.1.12
- I want the php-fpm container to connect to the redis service provided by one of the machines on the LAN
- php-fpm container IP is 172.25.0.4
- nginx container IP is laradock_frontend 172.24.0.3 laradock_backend 172.25.0.5
  a LAN has two segments: 192.168.1.0/24 and 192.168.10.0/24, redis service on 192.168.10.0/24 network segment， my own machine is on the 192.168.1.0/24 network segment.
- The document says that it can be configured as REDIS_HOST=redis

This is not suitable for me, I directly specify 192.168.10.244 display
Connection refused [tcp://192.168.10.244:6379]

what should I do?

Comment: Ignoring Docker for the moment, can you use `redis-cli` or `nc` to connect from your host system to the remote Redis server?

Comment: yes, can connect to a remote redis server directly from the host

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have two containers running `nginx` and `php-fpm` services on your computer with IP 192.168.1.12, and you're trying to reach a computer with IP 192.168.10.244 from one of the containers.

I'd try ensure both containers are on same network, created using `bridge` driver:

```
docker network create --driver bridge my-network
docker run --name nginx --network my-network nginx:stable ...
docker run --name php-fpm --network my-network php:rc-fpm ...
```

Comment: thank you for your answer.
I want to access redis services provided by other segments of the LAN through the php-fpm container